# Android App crashing on receipt of push notification

Tags: push-notification, appcelerator, google-cloud-messaging, appcelerator-mobile

My android application is crashing on receipt of push notification. The code im using is shown below

```
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');

var deviceToken =   '';
//fetch device token
CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
    success : function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
        alert('Device Token: ' + deviceToken);
        Ti.API.info('Device Token: ' + e.deviceToken);
    },
    error : function deviceTokenError(e) {
        alert('Failed to register for push! ' + e.error);
    }
});

CloudPush.debug = true;
CloudPush.enabled = true;
CloudPush.showTrayNotificationsWhenFocused = true;
CloudPush.focusAppOnPush = false;

CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function(evt) {
    alert(evt.payload);
});
```

Im unable to figure out what i am doing wrong or find any information on this issue.
Any information would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

PS - Im using Titanium SDK 3.1.0.

***Logs listed below -***

```
E/TiApplication(9474): (main) [27233,59667] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.appcelerator.titanium.TiApplication.isCurrentActivityInForeground; Titanium 3.1.0,2013/04/15 18:46,57634ef

E/TiApplication(9474): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.appcelerator.titanium.TiApplication.isCurrentActivityInForeground

E/TiApplication(9474): at ti.cloudpush.CloudpushModuleGeneric.receivePayload(CloudpushModuleGeneric.java:81)

E/TiApplication(9474): at ti.cloudpush.GCMReceiver.onReceive(GCMReceiver.java:26) E/TiApplication(9474): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2280)

E/TiApplication(9474): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:143) 
E/TiApplication(9474): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)

E/TiApplication(9474): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 

E/TiApplication(9474): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 

E/TiApplication(9474): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950) 

E/TiApplication(9474): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 

E/TiApplication(9474): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 

E/TiApplication(9474): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)

E/TiApplication(9474): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771) 
E/TiApplication(9474): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the version of cloudpush module you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is :

> E/TiApplication(9474): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.appcelerator.titanium.TiApplication.isCurrentActivityInForeground

Googling this method, I found it [here](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/android/titanium/src/java/org/appcelerator/titanium/TiApplication.java).

That means you are probably using a jar that contains a wrong version of the `org.appcelerator.titanium.TiApplication` class.

Answer (score 0):

I faced an issue while implementing the GCM push. It was due to the issue with CloudPush module I used. I was using CloudPush module 3.x. I changed the module back to 2.3.3 and it worked. Same issue will occur if your application is installed in Android 2.3.x devices. So try changing the Android CloudPush module to 2.3.3 and don't forget to specify the version on TiApp.xml